# Is it possible to initialize slice with specific values?

Tags: go, slice

Is it possible to initialize an slice with all 1's like in python?

PYTHON:

```
onesArray = np.ones(5)
onesList = [1]*5
```

GOLANG

```
onesSlice := make([]int, 5)
for i:= 0; i < len(onesSlice); i++{
    onesSlice[i] = 1
}
```

Is it possible to do better than this?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Yes but you have to use a different syntax.

```
oneSlice := []int{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

It's referred to as 'composite literal'

Also, if there is reason to iterate (like calculating the values based loop variable or something) then you could use the `range` keyword rather than the old school for i is equal to, i is less than, i++ loop.

```
for i := range onesSlice {
    onesSlice[i] = 1
}
```

Comment: `len(oneSlice)` == `cap(oneSlice)`

Comment: I want to create a slice containing `n` copies of integer `val`. Is there an easier way than looping? For example, in C++ I can do `vector<int> a(n, val)`.

Comment: There is no easy way in Go as of 1.16. It would be nice if you could write eg `make_init([]int, N, INIT_VAL)` could create a slice of N times INIT_VAL (with capacity N).